# ios how to check if object in array in particular index exist?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray

I have nsmutable array and I want to add object at particular index, how can I check if the array at particular index has a object or not?

I was doing this:

```
if ([self.myArray objectAtIndex:index] !=nil) {
```

but I'm getting exceptions most of the time because "beyond bounds"

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: You can't have a `nil` in an NS(Mutable)Array.  (Note that an NSNull object is different from `nil`.)  You *can* easily check the `count` of the array, to see if the element at an index has been allocated yet.

Comment: Lack of research. The way NSArray works is straightforward and well documented.

Comment: @matt -- He's just getting his feet wet.  Far better this question than "Write my program for me".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is my understanding that you cannot have an index of an array unless you have and object there. What I would suggest is to set all indexes in the array to `[NSNull null]` and then in your if statement check to see if the object at that index is an NSNull object. `if([[self.myArray objectAtIndex:index] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])` then if that returns true, have it replace the null object with your object

Comment: how can set objects in the array to [NSNull null] ?

Comment: Do you know how many indexes you want?

Answer (score 8):

Easiest (may be not the best) will be

```
if ([self.myArray count] > index && [self.myArray objectAtIndex:index] !=nil)
```

Comment: I'd add one more check: index >= 0, so you'll have 3 checks grouped by && operand.

Comment: But skip the `[self.myArray objectAtIndex:index] !=nil`, since it will always be true (except when myArray is nil, in which case the first test will fail).

Answer (score 0):

```
if( self.myArray != nil && [self.myArray count] >= (index - 1) ) { ... }
```

Comment: you don't need to check is array nil or not, sending message to nil is  fine.

Comment: Agree, it s a bad habit of mine.